# Shared library unloading and atexit handling - what order?

Tags: c, atexit

I'm debugging a sort of weird issue where it looks like a thread that's killed in an atexit handler is accessing a shared library, and is segfaulting because that shared library is unloaded before the exit handler runs. I'm not sure this is actually the issue, but it's a hunch on what might be happening.

When a process terminates (main exits or exit() is called), is the atexit handler the *immediate* next thing to run? My mind says so, but the segfault I'm seeing seems to say otherwise.

Is there any difference (with regards to exit handling) between main returning (either end of function or with return) and calling exit() directly?

Comment: Shared libraries in general and how they interact with threads and exit handlers in particular are implementation details.  Those three are a mix I would definitely try to avoid, myself.  To get an answer applicable to your particular circumstances, we would need to know more about your particular circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a process terminates (main exits or exit() is called), is the atexit handler the immediate next thing to run? My mind says so, but the segfault I'm seeing seems to say otherwise.

Not necessarily, you're guaranteed that `atexit` handlers will run. But that's it, `atexit` handlers may even be called concurrently with other things. While you're using [c](/questions/tagged/c) remember that [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) may be in the same process. C++ says that `atexit` may be called [concurrently to destructors being run](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) for objects of `static` duration. This means that `atexit` is very dangerous and you need to ensure you're being very careful what you call.

> Is there any difference (with regards to exit handling) between main returning (either end of function or with return) and calling exit() directly?

According to the documentation: No.

The safest thing to do when tearing down the house: Nothing. Just get out and let the house be torn down. Closing the drapes on the way out isn't worth the time so to speak.